# Disable AirDrop by writing DisableAirDrop to group com.apple.NetworkBrowser

Tags: macos, defaults, airdrop

I'd like to know if there's any difference in behavior when I try to set AirDrop off using `sudo` or as regular user :

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser DisableAirDrop -bool YES

defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser DisableAirDrop -bool YES
```

Does the `root` configuration "wins" the user configuration ?

Does the `root` configuration applies to all users ?

thanks